# Counting the number of appearances of each id in a table sql db2

Tags: sql, database, select, db2

I have two tables in my sql database

> product: PID(PK), PName
>   Sales: PID(FK), Quantity, Price

I just want to implement a query to count how many times each PID was repeated in the sales table

I have tried this code:

```
> select count(PID) from sales where PID = 'P01';
```

but i have to insert a particular ID number to count it. the issue i i want all the IDs.
I wish someone can help pe on this.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by `PID` and count the occurances within each group:

```
select 
    PID, 
    count(*) as PIDCount
from 
    sales 
group by 
    PID;
```

Comment: ohhh i have totally forgotten the group by statement, thank you very much.

Comment: This question is tagged with **db2**, but the SQL statement shown in the solution will fail if executed on DB2.  (ANSI SQL requires you to write the expression as `count(*) as PIDCount`)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated. I prefer the non-ANSI 'Columnname' = value  (when using RDBMS's that support it) as it is more readable when scanning a left aligned, long column list.